# error when handling intents sent by GCM

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I had some errors on "" class when I was handling the GCM .
the error appeared here :

```
onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
```

> "Cannot override the final method from GCMBaseIntentService"

```
handleRegistration
```

> "The method handleRegistration(Context, Intent) in the type
>   GCMBaseIntentService is not applicable for the arguments (Intent)"

```
handleMessage
```

> "The method handleMessage(Intent) is undefined for the type
>   GCMIntenetService"

```
public final void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
            try {
                String action = intent.getAction();
                if (action.equals("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION")) {
                    handleRegistration(intent);
                } else if (action.equals("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE")) {
                    handleMessage(intent);
                }
            } finally {
                synchronized (LOCK) {
                    sWakeLock.release();
                }
            }
        }
```

class

```
package com.example.elarabygroup;

import com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.util.Log;

public class GCMIntenetService extends GCMBaseIntentService {
    public static String TAG = "GCMIntentService";
    private static PowerManager.WakeLock sWakeLock;
    private static final Object LOCK = GCMIntenetService.class;

    /*Handling Intents sent by GCM*/
    static void runIntentInService(Context context, Intent intent) {
        synchronized (LOCK) {
            if (sWakeLock == null) {
                PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
                sWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
                        "my_wakelock");
            }
        }
        sWakeLock.acquire();
        intent.setClassName(context, GCMIntenetService.class.getName());
        context.startService(intent);
    }



    public GCMIntenetService(String senderId) {
        super(senderId);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        Log.d(TAG, "[GCMIntentService] start - sender Id : " + senderId);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onError(Context arg0, String arg1) {
        Log.d("onError", arg1);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onRecoverableError(Context context, String errorId) {
        Log.d("onRecoverableError", errorId);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    /*
     * protected void onMessage(Context arg0, Intent arg1) { Log.d("onMessage",
     * String.valueOf(arg1)); }
     */
    protected void onMessage(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {

        Log.d("GCM", "RECIEVED A MESSAGE");
        // Get the data from intent and send to notificaion bar
        generateNotification(arg0, arg1.getStringExtra("**notificaion**"));
    }

    private void generateNotification(Context arg0, String stringExtra) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    protected void onRegistered(intent) {

    try {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action.equals("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION")) {
            handleRegistration(intent);
        } else if (action.equals("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE")) {
            handleMessage(intent);
        }
    } finally {
        synchronized (LOCK) {
            sWakeLock.release();
        }
    }

}

    @Override
    protected void onUnregistered(Context arg0, String arg1) {
        Log.d("onUnregistered", arg1);
    }
}
```

Comment: You try override private final method  handleRegistration(intent);

Comment: Remove HandleIntent() function and use onRegistered(),onUnregistered(),OnMessage and etc..

Comment: and on onRegistered(),onUnregistered(),OnMessage and etc I dosenot add any code  or what?

Comment: Handle registration here : OnRegistered(){ hande registration code } instead   handleRegistration(intent);

Comment: I did , but I had error to remove @override .I edited the code you can check and I hope if you write your code as an answer

Comment: if (action.equals("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE")) {
            handleMessage(intent);
        } - that should be in OnMessage(). And dont! use handeMessage and handeRegistration

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16550/discussion-between-egydeveloper-and-yahor10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't override final methods of GCMBaseIntentService. You need ovveride only callback methods of this base class. Here is an example:

```
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

    private static final String GCM_SENDER_ID = "your_sender_id";

    public GCMIntentService() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRegistered(Context context, String gcmDeviceToken) {
        // remember and save somewhere "gcmDeviceToken"
    }

    @Override
    protected void onUnregistered(Context context, String s) {
        // Push unregistered processing
    }

    @Override
    protected void onError(Context context, String errorId) {
        // push error processing
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // process Push message
    }

    public static void registerInGCMService(Context context) {
        if (!checkIsGCMServiceAvailable(context)) {
            return;
        }
        final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(context);
        if (regId.equals("")) {
            try {
                GCMRegistrar.register(context, GCM_SENDER_ID);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        } else {
            // Already registered
        }
    }

    public static boolean checkIsGCMServiceAvailable(Context context) {
        try {
            GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(context);
            GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(context);
            return true;
        } catch (Throwable th) {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

UPDATE: please note - you should change value of **GCM_SENDER_ID** constant with your own, it should be numeric value, something like "1234567890123"

Comment: Of course if can't be resolved, because it's my custom implementation of logging. Ok, I've removed all occurrence of this class. Code above will work fine without Logger.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Device registered: regId = " + registrationId);
        GCMRegistrar.setRegisteredOnServer(context, true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
        Log.i(TAG, "EXTRAS" + intent.getExtras());
        String message = getString(R.string.gcm_message);
        // notifies user about message

    }

    @Override
    protected void onUnregistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Device unregistered");
        if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(context)) {
                Log.i(TAG, "unregistering device (regId = " + regId + ")");
        GCMRegistrar.setRegisteredOnServer(context, false);
        } else {
            // This callback results from the call to unregister made on
            // ServerUtilities when the registration to the server failed.
            Log.i(TAG, "Ignoring unregister callback");
        }
    }
```

See GCM google tutorial http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html

Comment: this error appeared gcm_message cannot be resolved or is not a field